# Arctan Taylor Series in C

Tags: c

I need to perform the Taylor Series for arctangent 50 times. Meaning 50 numbers between the domain of the arctan Taylor Series which is [-1,1]. I've tested it out with manual user input and it works fine, but the for loop for the 50 different inputs which I increment in the code by 0.01 and their corresponding results has been unsuccessful. I've tried everything I could think of so far, I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. Is there an issue with my brackets surrounding the Taylor Series that's conflicting with the other for loop? I've suspected it was the brackets but nothings worked when I attempted to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main (void) {
    double n;
    double x;
    double tSeries=0.0;
    double t2;
    double t1;

    for(n=0;n<=50;++n) {
        for(x=-1;x<=1;x=x+0.01) {

            t1=(pow(x,2*n+1))*pow(-1,n);
            t2=t1/(2*n+1);
            tSeries+=t2;

            printf("arctan(%lf)=%lf\n",x,tSeries);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your description seems rather confused, and the code doesn't help much.  It looks like `x` represents the argument of the arctangent function, but that variable takes 201 different values over the course of your program, not 50.  Variable `n` takes 51 values in the program, but this appears to represent the degree of a term in the expansion.  At best, you have the nesting backward -- the loop over `x` should be the outer one, or so it appears to me.

Comment: You should use a function to calculate the arctangent of a value that's passed in.  Then arrange a loop to call that with the different values, and print the result each time around the loop.  That would avoid the problems.  Functions are your friends.

Comment: Note that repeated increments of floating point numbers is a bad idea in general.  "Floating point numbers are like little piles of sand; every time you move one, you lose a little sand and you gain a little dirt" (Kernighan & Plauger — The Elements of Programming Style, quoting that prolific author 'anonymous').  You could use `for (int i = -100; i <= 100; i++) { double x = i / 100.0; … }` to get better accuracy. You can declare variables at the top of a block (after a `{`) in any version of C, and it is good to reduce the scope of variables to a minimum.

Comment: no need to calculate `pow(x,2*n+1)` and `pow(-1,n)` again and again each iteration, which is extremely inefficient. Simply multiply by x*x and flip the sign after each iteration

Answer (score 2):

In the code you've posted the inner loop is over the variable x, and the outer loop is over the power n.

I think you want to sum over values of n for each value of x, so the loop over n should be the inner loop.

I think you also need to zero your sum, tSeries for each value of x.

Finally, I expect you want to print the answer after calculating the sum, so printf should be outside the n loop.

There are a few tricks to the evaluation of power series. I like Numerical Recipes for this sort of thing. Try chapter 5 on the evaluation of functions. (Numerical Recipes in C, Press et al., 2nd Ed., 1992, CUP.)

One thing to note right away is that with the upper limit of the power series fixed, you are evaluating a polynomial. Section 5.3 of my copy of NR recommends strongly against using a sum of calls to pow(). They are quite firm about it!

Let me know if you want me to post correct code.

Comment: Did they change the license of Numerical Recipes or why do you suggest it?

Comment: I don't have the codes from Numerical Recipes, but I do have the book on my desk. When I need to code a numerical algorithm I always check to see what NR says about it. It's saved me a huge amount of time. I am not sure of the licensing arrangements if you want to use their exact codes.

Comment: I know a lot of the stipulations I had in my OP were rather odd but some of things I can control and are designated by my instructor to be a certain way. I appreciate the help though and I'll definitely take a look at that text to help me with future endeavors in C. I've figured it out, but thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You got the loops mixed, the inner one goes out and vice versa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  double n;
  double x;
  double tSeries = 0.0;
  double t2;
  double t1;

  for (x = -1; x <= 1; x += 0.01) {
    for (n = 0; n <= 50; n++) {
      t1 = (pow(x, 2 * n + 1)) * pow(-1, n);
      t2 = t1 / (2 * n + 1);
      tSeries += t2;
    }
    printf("arctan(%lf)=%lf (%lf)\n", x, tSeries, atan(x));
    tSeries = 0.0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to reset `tSeries = 0.0;` before the start of the inner loop?

Comment: Ooh: please: — `double tSeries = 0.0;` just inside the outer loop and eliminate the variable outside.  You could declare and initialize `t1` and `t2` inside the inner loop.  And, at a slightly larger level, the inner loop should all be in an arctangent function — which would have avoided the problems with the inverted loops in the first place.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler always my pleasure to please others ;-) I tried to change as little as possible. Got hit over my head here for doing too much. And furthermore: running the sum that way is not the best way. With a fixed number of rounds Horner's scheme is better. Also `pow(-1,n)`? No, it's easy to understand for a beginner as it is, don't push too much.

Comment: I'm a little ashamed the bracket fix seemed so easy and trivial. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: OK; fair enough.  I have a strong preference for declaring variables in the minimum scope, and initializing before use rather than reinitializing before next use, but I can respect your alternative.  And there are many numerical issues in the code — see one of my comments to the main question for one such issue, though the series expansion algorithm would be another.

Comment: @cphoenix you've asked a proper question here, with all the needed code included, and got help. great! you should also *accept* one of the answers in such cases, the one that helped you the most; you'll get a +2 reputation for it (in case you didn't know). It's also a good way to show appreciation -- the answerer gets +15 rep for their efforts.